# how to save input from text field into local storage then display item in column after button click in Angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, input

[display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9A60.png)

How do i store user input into todo array and then into local storage, then display into todo column.
how to save input from text field into local storage then display item in column after button click in Angular.

template:

```
<div cdkDropListGroup>
  <div class="example-container">
    <h2>TO DO</h2>

    <div
      cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListData]="todo"
      class="example-list"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="example-container">
    <h2>IN PROGRESS</h2>

    <div
      cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListData]="inprogress"
      class="example-list"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of inprogress" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="example-container">
    <h2>DONE</h2>

    <div
      cdkDropList
      [cdkDropListData]="done"
      class="example-list"
      (cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)">
      <div class="example-box" *ngFor="let item of done" cdkDrag>{{item}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

    <form >
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
        <mat-label>New task</mat-label>
        <input
          matInput placeholder="Ex. Check email"
          *ngFor="let item of todo">
      </mat-form-field>
      
      <button mat-mini-fab color="primary" (Click)="onAdd()">+</button>

drag and drop columns from Angular material UI in template.

ts file:

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'task-board';
  


  todo = ['new task'];

  inprogress = [
    'Get to work',
    'Pick up groceries',
    'Go home',
    'Fall asleep'
  ];

  done = [
    'Get up',
    'Brush teeth',
    'Take a shower',
    'Check e-mail',
    'Walk dog'
  ];


  drop(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    if (event.previousContainer === event.container) {
      moveItemInArray(event.container.data, event.previousIndex, event.currentIndex);
    } else {
      transferArrayItem(event.previousContainer.data,
                        event.container.data,
                        event.previousIndex,
                        event.currentIndex);
    }
  }
```

how do i add correct logic to store and display into todo.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ngx-pwa/local-storage